# How to use WSO2 identity server without a tenant?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I just really want to understand the configuration of the identity server without a tenant and how it handles the users and their login. Please help.

Comment: The question is too broad. Having tenants is optional in WSO2 products. By default, it will only have 1 tenant (aka. Super Tenant)

Answer (score 3):

Multi tenancy is introduced to logically separate data (which belong to different organizations), despite being stored with the same Identity Server and in the same database.

Say that you are handling Identities for a group of companies where the existence of Company A shouldn't be known to Company B. In this case you can consider A and B as two different tenants.

Regarding the users and login :

In WSO2 the default tenant is `carbon.super` and you can define your own tenants as well (i.e. `abc.com`, `xyz.com`). In the IS(Identity Server), we are storing users in the user stores (LDAP, AD, JDBC). There's a Primary user store (Defined in the `user-mgt.xml` file) and you can define your own secondary user stores.

When you create a secondary user store (`business_users`) in tenant `abc.com` (in any tenant) and add user `John` there, that user `john` is only available within that tenant. Also that secondary user store `business_users` is not visible from any other tenant beside the one in which it has configured.

But this `PRIMARY` user store (one that is defined in `user-mgt.xml` file) is visible to all the tenants. **But not all the users there are shared with all the tenants**. Means, from `xyz.com` tenant, you can add user `John` to the `PRIMARY` user store. You can again add user `John` from tenant `abc.com` as well. These users will be treated as two different users through out the server. One's existence is independent of, and unknown to the other. Fully qualified user names of these users inside the WSO2 IS server would be as `John@xyz.com` and `John@abc.com`.

Therefore, if you are performing a login to a service provider created in the `xyz.com` tenant, you can only login with the users who are visible (or defined within) that tenant it self.

P.S. You can define a shared Service Provider (SaaS app) if you want users from all the tenants to be able to login to your application.